# How can I assign different random values to each row in a SELECT statement?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Please look at this code:

```
create table #t1(
  id int identity (1,1),
  val varchar(10)
);


insert into #t1 values ('a');
insert into #t1 values ('b');
insert into #t1 values ('c');
insert into #t1 values ('d');
```

Now, whenever you execute this

```
select *, 
    ( select top 1 val from #t1 order by NEWID()) rnd 
from #t1 order by 1;
```

you will get a result with where all rows have the same random value. e.g.

```
id          val        rnd
----------- ---------- ----------
1           a          b
2           b          b
3           c          b
4           d          b
```

I know a way using a cursor to loop throw the rows and get different random values, but that is not performant.

A clever solution to this is

```
select t1.id, t1.val, t2.val
from #t1 t1
    join (select *, ROW_NUMBER() over( order by NEWID()) lfd from #t1) as t2 on  t1.id = t2.lfd
```

But I simplified the query. The real query looks more like

```
select *, 
    ( select top 1 val from t2 where t2.x <> t1.y order by NEWID()) rnd 
from t1 order by 1;
```

and the simple solution doesn't fit. I'm looking for a way to force repeated evaluation of

```
( select top 1 val from #t1 order by NEWID()) rnd
```

without the use of cursors.

Edit:
Wanted output:

perhaps 1 call

```
id          val        rnd
----------- ---------- ----------
1           a          c
2           b          c
3           c          b
4           d          a
```

and a second call

```
id          val        rnd
----------- ---------- ----------
1           a          a
2           b          d
3           c          d
4           d          b
```

The value for each row just should be a random value independent from the other rows

Here is the cursor version of the code:

```
CREATE TABLE #res ( id INT, val VARCHAR(10), rnd VARCHAR(10));

DECLARE @id INT
DECLARE @val VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE c CURSOR FOR
SELECT id, val
FROM #t1
OPEN c
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @id, @val
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #res
    SELECT @id, @val, ( SELECT TOP 1 val FROM #t1 ORDER BY NEWID()) rnd 
    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @id, @val
END
CLOSE c
DEALLOCATE c

SELECT * FROM #res
```

Comment: What would be your perfect output please? maybe I'm missing something

Comment: I'm preparing a cursor version to make it clear

Comment: So rnd and val are always different in every row? If it was "random", then occasionally they would the same. Also, in your 2 calls mentioned does it matter that rnd does not have all values on the column?

Comment: It is used to generate a small to medium random demonstration from a big pool of real data. Yes repletions are allowed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A subquery is evaluated once if possible. I can't recall what the "feature" is called (folding?) sorry.

The same applies to GETDATE and RAND functions. NEWID is evaluated row by row because it in intrinsically a random value and should never generate the same value twice.

The usual techniques are to use use NEWID as input to CHECKSUM or as a seed to RAND

For random values per row:

```
SELECT
   co1l, col2,
   ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) AS Random1,
   RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) AS Random2
FROM
   MyTable
```

If you want random order:

```
SELECT
   co1l, col2
FROM
   MyTable
ORDER BY
   NEWID()
```

If you want random order with a row order too. ActualOrder order here is preserved regardless of the order of the resultset

```
SELECT
   id, val,
   ROWNUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS id
FROM
   #t1
ORDER BY
   NEWID()
```

Edit:

In this case, we can state the requirement as:

> 1. return any random value from the set for each row in the set
> 2. the random value will be different from the actual value in any row

This is different to what I offered above which simply re-orders rows in various ways

So, I'd consider CROSS APPLY. The WHERE clause force row by row evaluation and avoids the "folding" issue *and* ensures that val and rnd are always different. CROSS APPLY can scale quite well too

```
SELECT
   id, val, R.rnd
FROM
   #t1 t1
   CROSS APPLY
   (SELECT TOP 1 val as rnd FROM #t1 t2 WHERE t1.val <> t2.val ORDER BY NEWID()) R
ORDER BY
   id
```

Comment: APPLY is **SQL Server 2005** and upper

Comment: @bernd_k: yep, but it should be realistic to ignore SQL Server 2000 users in 2011...